# specify marksweep gc for `spark-submit` job on emr

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm, amazon-emr

How do I specify that I want the jvm to use the MarkSweep gc when running a `spark-submit` job on emr?  Can I submit it with the job (i.e. `spark-submit -- conf...`) and if so, what is the command?  Does this have to be set by the time spark starts and, if so,  how do I specify that in the emr config?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify JVM options in the `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=<YourJavaOptionsHere>"` following the `spark-submit`.

For example, running PageRank example of graphX with ParallelScavenge GC would be like this:

`spark-submit run-example --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseParallelGC" graphx.PageRankExample`

More information is at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment